# how to make a header responsive and keep svg at center?

Tags: svg, responsive, center

Hi all I already have it looking centered and responsive but I am not sure if there is anything else I can do to make it even better
I have this structure:

```
div
   div
      svg
```

the first div has

```
width 100%
```

second has

```
display flex 
align items center
```

then for the svg I have it's size:

```
svg[Attributes Style] {
    width: 85;
    height: 21;
}
```

What else can I do? I am testing it in various screens but I haven't found issues yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
div div { ## this is the second <div> tag
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and
`svg {text-align: center;}`